# Selecting first and last scores from a list of appointments

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a database of appointments, each with a personid, sequence number, appointment date and two questionnaire scores.

What I need to do is bring back one line per personid, showing their first appointment with scores, and their last appointment with scores, along with the scores themselves for both.

Having spent a long time already on what is probably a very simple query, I've tried to use the following to just give me the first appointment with scores:

```
SELECT 
PERSONID,
MIN(CONTACTDATE) AS 'FIRST_CONTACT',
QUEST_1,
QUEST_2

FROM TBL_APPOINTMENTS

GROUP BY
PERSONID,
CONTACTDATE,
QUEST_1,
QUEST_2

ORDER BY 
PERSONID,
FIRST_CONTACT
```

As you can probably guess, this is giving me duplicate rows every time the values in QUEST_1 or QUEST_2 change.

Can anyone help please? I'm sure this is all very simple but it's driving me up the wall!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sample data would help.  In particular, what is this supposed to add?  ", along with the scores themselves for both"

Comment: Your mean is when you select a row, its previous and next row be selected too and three row return?

Comment: What about adding Q1 and Q2 in single row i.e. SELECT QUEST_1 + ',' + QUEST_2 AS QUEST from table.
This is on what i understood the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the result you're looking for is something like this:

```
PERSONID    FIRST_CONTACT FIRST_QUEST_1 FIRST_QUEST_2 LAST_CONTACT LAST_QUEST_1 LAST_QUEST_2
----------- ------------- ------------- ------------- ------------ ------------ ------------
1           2015-01-01    10            11            2015-01-21   21           211
2           2015-01-01    11            24            2015-01-31   12           25
3           2015-02-01    13            21            2015-03-01   14           28
4           2015-03-01    15            29            2015-04-01   16           21
```

then the query below would give you that. Note that the max and min dates and scores would be the same if there is only one record for a person.

```
SELECT 
    PERSONID, 
    FIRST_CONTACT, FIRST_QUEST_1, FIRST_QUEST_2, 
    LAST_CONTACT, LAST_QUEST_1, LAST_QUEST_2
FROM (
    SELECT PERSONID, MIN(CONTACTDATE) AS 'FIRST_CONTACT', MAX(CONTACTDATE) AS 'LAST_CONTACT' 
    FROM TBL_APPOINTMENTS a 
    GROUP BY PERSONID
) a
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT QUEST_1 AS 'FIRST_QUEST_1', QUEST_2  AS 'FIRST_QUEST_2'
    FROM TBL_APPOINTMENTS 
    WHERE PERSONID = a.PERSONID AND CONTACTDATE = A.FIRST_CONTACT
) o_first
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT QUEST_1 AS 'LAST_QUEST_1', QUEST_2  AS 'LAST_QUEST_2'
    FROM TBL_APPOINTMENTS 
    WHERE PERSONID = a.PERSONID AND CONTACTDATE = A.LAST_CONTACT
) o_last
ORDER BY PERSONID, FIRST_CONTACT;
```

The same query could be written using joins:

```
SELECT 
    A.PERSONID, 
    FIRST_CONTACT, 
    F.QUEST_1 AS FIRST_QUEST_1, 
    F.QUEST_2 AS FIRST_QUEST_2, 
    LAST_CONTACT, 
    L.QUEST_1 AS LAST_QUEST_1, 
    L.QUEST_2 AS LAST_QUEST_2
FROM (
    SELECT PERSONID, MIN(CONTACTDATE) AS 'FIRST_CONTACT', MAX(CONTACTDATE) AS 'LAST_CONTACT' 
    FROM TBL_APPOINTMENTS a 
    GROUP BY PERSONID
) a
JOIN TBL_APPOINTMENTS F ON F.PERSONID = a.PERSONID AND A.FIRST_CONTACT = F.CONTACTDATE
JOIN TBL_APPOINTMENTS L ON L.PERSONID = a.PERSONID AND A.LAST_CONTACT = L.CONTACTDATE
ORDER BY A.PERSONID, FIRST_CONTACT;
```

Comment: I don't think you need to use `APPLY` here.  You could simply join on to the table.  *(Using `APPLY` for this scenario would seem to be more appropriate if it were like `person OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 FROM appointment WHERE person = person ORDER BY contactdate ASC) AS o_first`, so as to avoid the initial aggregate pass through on the appointments table.)*

Comment: @MatBailie Yeah, I just thought it looked cleaner with the apply as the code got reduced a bit. Both versions generated the same execution plan in my test so I don't think either should be better for performance (although my test was of course limited to a very small sample).

Comment: You don't even need the sub-queries.  `(aggregate) a LEFT JOIN appointments o_first ON blah LEFT JOIN appointments o_last ON blah`  Removing the sub-queries should keep it a lot tidier.

Comment: @MatBailie Was it something like that you meant?

Comment: Thanks very much for the swift response - the first solution works a treat.

Answer (score 1):

Using `ROW_NUMBER()` you can assign appointments a sequential value starting from `1` on a per `PERSONID` basis.

In the example below I create two such ordinals, one forward in time, and one reverse in time.  then I can pick the `first going forward` as well as the `first going backwards`.

```
WITH
  sorted AS
(
  SELECT
    PERSONID,
    CONTACTDATE,
    QUEST_1,
    QUEST_2,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PERSONID ORDER BY CONTACTDATE  ASC)   AS ORD_FWD,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PERSONID ORDER BY CONTACTDATE DESC)   AS ORD_REV
  FROM
    TBL_APPOINTMENTS
)
SELECT
  PERSONID,
  CONTACTDATE,
  QUEST_1,
  QUEST_2
FROM
  sorted
WHERE
  ORD_FWD = 1 OR ORD_REV = 1
ORDER BY
  PERSONID,
  CONTACTDATE
```

**EDIT** *With both first and last aggregated in to one row...*

```
WITH
  sorted AS
(
  SELECT
    PERSONID,
    CONTACTDATE,
    QUEST_1,
    QUEST_2,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PERSONID ORDER BY CONTACTDATE  ASC)   AS ORD_FWD,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PERSONID ORDER BY CONTACTDATE DESC)   AS ORD_REV
  FROM
    TBL_APPOINTMENTS
)
SELECT
  PERSONID,
  MAX(CASE WHEN ORD_FWD = 1 THEN CONTACTDATE END)   AS FIRST_CONTACTDATE,
  MAX(CASE WHEN ORD_FWD = 1 THEN QUEST_1     END)   AS FIRST_QUEST_1,
  MAX(CASE WHEN ORD_FWD = 1 THEN QUEST_2     END)   AS FIRST_QUEST_2,
  MAX(CASE WHEN ORD_REV = 1 THEN CONTACTDATE END)   AS FINAL_CONTACTDATE,
  MAX(CASE WHEN ORD_REV = 1 THEN QUEST_1     END)   AS FINAL_QUEST_1,
  MAX(CASE WHEN ORD_REV = 1 THEN QUEST_2     END)   AS FINAL_QUEST_2
FROM
  sorted
WHERE
  ORD_FWD = 1 OR ORD_REV = 1
GROUP BY
  PERSONID
ORDER BY
  PERSONID
```

NOTE: It is possible that the first and last appointment are the same appointment *(if the person only had one appointment)*.

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT PERSONID,
    MIN(CONTACTDATE) AS 'FIRST_CONTACT', MAX(CONTACTDATE) AS 'LAST_CONTACT'
    QUEST_1,
    QUEST_2
    FROM TBL_APPOINTMENTS
    GROUP BY PERSONID,
CONTACTDATE,
QUEST_1,
QUEST_2
 ORDER BY 
    PERSONID,
    FIRST_CONTACT
```

Comment: You missed out the `FROM` clause.  And in SQL SERVER you can't select `QUEST_1` or `QUEST_2` as they're not in the `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: @MatBailie sorry it was just a typo